# How to alter startup folder contents on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

How can I access the startup folder on Windows 7?

The GoToMyPC program pops up whenever I log in, and I do not use it that frequently.

Therefore I would like to remove it from the startup folder.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/81671/what-is-the-best-software-for-managing-startup-applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start -> All Programs, right-click Startup, and choose "Explore" (for your own settings), or "Open All Users" (for all user settings), and remove the program shortcut from that folder.