# placed startup folder at D:\ on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot

On Win7, I moved my startup folder to be at "D:\"

I clicked OK by accident! Really!

Using [this](https://superuser.com/questions/459587/how-to-alter-startup-folder-contents-on-windows-7) method is no longer possible, I don't have a "move" option anymore.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just use a system restoration point one is created before an update is installed.

Comment: How did you really move the folder? Using `Location` property or cut-paste?

Comment: Well, that was a great idea, but sadly I have restore system disabled :(

Comment: Using Properties\Location\MoveButton, then placed it on D:\, almost pressed on the Startup folder but clicked space and it moved it.

Answer (score 1):

If you moved your startup folder to `D:\`:

1. Right-click the folder `Startup` that's now located at `D:\Startup`
2. Choose `Properties`
3. Find the `Location` tab
4. Click `Restore Default`

It will now move back to the default location.

Comment: Startup folder is D:\. My startup DP Icon is now at "D:\Dropbox.lnk".

Comment: Aaah. Does the disk have the Location tab?

Comment: Tried it before replying. It doesn't, seems like they merged: "Files in the Media (D:) folder are stored in the target location below...". Anyway to restore custom folders to default location?

Comment: I think you can move it by editing the `Startup` property in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`. Even if that works, I don't think you'll get the `Location` tab etc. in the new folder. To retrieve that, you could try to copy a working startup folder from another user profile. If that doesn't restore it, you can delete your user profile using "SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe", but be aware that this deletes your registry unless you backup "Ntuser.dat", "Ntuser.dat.log" and "Ntuser.ini" from `C:\users\yourname`

Comment: eh, I hoped, but that solution didn't work too. bad stuff. guess deleting my user is the only way to go.